# Forward unix domain socket to tcp port

Tags: tcp, forward, unix-socket

I know `socat` can forward unix socket to tcp port and it forwards all package.

But I just want to send some package, not at all. Is there nodejs (or other languages) source code to forward unix socket to tcp port and it can filter the packages ?

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are asking. Do you want to find a product/tool where you could make arbitrary modification (which likely requires you to program the kind of modifications you want), do you want to help in programming such thing yourself (which language and please show your own attempts first) or do you want to make specific modifications (which ones)? Please edit your question to provide the missing details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I edited my question. plz check it